# PayPal Adaptive Payments Error: API credentials are incorrect. Error Code: 520003

Tags: php, paypal

I'm attempting to use PayPal's PHP SDK with their Adaptive Payments API to create a back end script to automate the payment of our website's affiliates. I've set the following constants to the corresponding values I've been given by paypal:

```
define('API_AUTHENTICATION_MODE','3token');
define('API_USERNAME', 'xxx');
define('API_PASSWORD', 'xxx');
define('API_SIGNATURE', 'xxx');
define('PAYPAL_REDIRECT_URL', 'https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=');
define('DEVELOPER_PORTAL', 'https://developer.paypal.com');
define('DEVICE_ID', 'PayPal_Platform_PHP_SDK');
define('APPLICATION_ID', 'xxx'); //(Using correct APP ID given by paypal after registering application
```

Where 'xxx' equals the correct values.

Is there something I'm missing? Every time I attempt to send a payment with our account I get error 520003.

This is my function that attempts to send payments:

```
function ImplicitPayment() {
    global $Accounts1;
    global $Accounts;
    global $Affiliates;
    global $fault;
    global $mAmount;
    global $mCompanyName;
    global $mEditAffiliate_ID;
    global $mEmailAffiliate;
    global $mLocalFlag;
    global $mPayPalEmailAccount;
    global $mToday;
    global $mPayPalTestEmail;
    global $mLocalFlag;


    if (!isset($Affiliates)) {
        $Affiliates = new DB('affiliates');
    }

    $Affiliates->select('SELECT * FROM affiliates
                                                LEFT JOIN accounts
                                                ON accounts.EMAIL_NO = affiliates.EMAIL_NO
                                                WHERE affiliates.AFFILIATE = %d
                                                    AND affiliates.ACTIVE = 1
                                                    AND affiliates.SHUTOFF != 1
                                                    AND affiliates.DELETED != 1
                                                    AND accounts.ACTIVE = 1
                                                    AND accounts.SHUTOFF != 1;', $mEditAffiliate_ID);
    $Affiliates->getNext();

    if (FALSE) {
        if (date('d') < 10) {
            //make commission payment late (at beginning of month 2)
            $mAmount = $Affiliates->d->COMM_DUE - $Affiliates->d->COMM - $Affiliates->d->COMM1;
        } else {
            $mAmount = $Affiliates->d->COMM_DUE - $Affiliates->d->COMM;
        }
    }


    $mAmount = $_REQUEST['mAmount'];

    $mEmailAffiliate = $Affiliates->d->EMAIL;

    include_once(SCRIPTPATH . '/admin/paypal_adaptive_payments/AdaptivePayments.php');
    include_once(SCRIPTPATH . '/admin/paypal_adaptive_payments/web_constants.php');

    try {

    /* The servername and serverport tells PayPal where the buyer
        should be directed back to after authorizing payment.
        In this case, its the local webserver that is running this script
        Using the servername and serverport, the return URL is the first
        portion of the URL that buyers will return to after authorizing payment                */

        $serverName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        $serverPort = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
        $url=dirname('http://'.$serverName.':'.$serverPort.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

        /* The returnURL is the location where buyers return when a
        payment has been succesfully authorized.
        The cancelURL is the location buyers are sent to when they hit the
        cancel button during authorization of payment during the PayPal flow                 */

        $returnURL = 'http://www.realadventures.com/'; //$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        $cancelURL = 'http://www.realadventures.com/'; //$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        $currencyCode = 'USD';
        $email = $mPayPalEmailAccount; //$_REQUEST["email"];
        $preapprovalKey = "";       // No preapprovalKey for an implicit use case
        $requested = '';
        $receiverEmail = '';
        $count = 1; //count($_POST['receiveremail']);

        $payRequest = new PayRequest();
        $payRequest->actionType = "PAY";
        $payRequest->cancelUrl = $cancelURL;
        $payRequest->returnUrl = $returnURL;
        $payRequest->clientDetails = new ClientDetailsType();
        $payRequest->clientDetails->applicationId = APPLICATION_ID;
        $payRequest->clientDetails->deviceId = DEVICE_ID;
        $payRequest->clientDetails->ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
        $payRequest->currencyCode = $currencyCode;
        $payRequest->senderEmail = $email;
        $payRequest->requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope();
        $payRequest->requestEnvelope->errorLanguage = "en_US";

        if ($preapprovalKey != "") {
            $payRequest->preapprovalKey = $preapprovalKey;
        }

        $receiver1 = new receiver();
        $receiver1->email = $mEmailAffiliate; //$_POST['receiveremail'][0];
        $receiver1->amount = $mAmount;

        $payRequest->receiverList = new ReceiverList();
        $payRequest->receiverList = array($receiver1);

        /* Make the call to PayPal to get the Pay token
        If the API call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal
        to begin to authorize payment.  If an error occured, show the
        resulting errors */

        $ap = new AdaptivePayments();
        $response=$ap->Pay($payRequest);

        if (strtoupper($ap->isSuccess) == 'FAILURE') {
            $_SESSION['FAULTMSG'] = $ap->getLastError();
            DisplayErrors();

            //$location = "APIError.php";
            //header("Location: $location");
        } else {
            $_SESSION['payKey'] = $response->payKey;
            if ($response->paymentExecStatus == "COMPLETED") {
                //DisplayDetails();
                //$location = "PaymentDetails.php";
                //header("Location: $location");
            } else {

                $token = $response->payKey;
                $payPalURL = PAYPAL_REDIRECT_URL.'_ap-payment&paykey='.$token;

                DisplayErrors();

                //header("Location: ".$payPalURL);
            }
        }

    }   catch(Exception $ex) {

        $fault = new FaultMessage();
        $errorData = new ErrorData();
        $errorData->errorId = $ex->getFile() ;
            $errorData->message = $ex->getMessage();
            $fault->error = $errorData;
        $_SESSION['FAULTMSG']=$fault;

        DisplayErrors();

        //$location = SCRIPTPATH . "/admin/APIError.php";
        //header("Location: $location");

    }

}
```

EDIT:
Also, $mPayPalEmailAccount is set to the same value as API_USERNAME